# Preserve existing tags in Anki CSV import/batch-add tags

Tags: batch, csv, import, anki

I have downloaded the complete 2012 HSK vocabulary from [here](http://www.chinesetest.cn/godownload.do), where it is available as [an excel file](http://www.chinesetest.cn/userfiles/file/HSK/HSK-2012.xls). I have then converted it to .CSV and changed it to this form:

```
爱;HSK:1
…
做主;HSK:6
```

The first field denominates the Chinese entry (`爱`), the semicolon (`;`) is the field separator and the second field is a tag (`HSK:1`)
As I already have a large number of Chinese words in my Anki database, I do not want to just import all of these blindly, but I would like to import them into Anki with the following prerequisites:

- Anki should check for duplicates of the Chinese entry and then

  - if the entry exists, *add* the tag to the existing and keep the already existing ones,
  - if it does not exist, import it normally.

The problem I have encountered is that if I map the first field to the `Simplified characters` field of my note type, the second field to `Tags` and select the option `Update existing notes when first field matches`, Anki deletes the preexisting tags and only the `HSK:*` tag will remain.

So how can I batch-add tags to an Anki deck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it is not possible via Anki itself, but there is [an add-on](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/2750889654) which can be used to import additional tags. To use, just follow the description on the linked site.

Comment: I've been looking for something like this for a while. However, it doesn't seem to work in Anki 2.0.36.